# Why do mosquitos prefer my right arm?

Tags: backpacking, bugs

I just got back from a 5-day backpacking trip on the Superior Hiking Trail in northern Minnesota and the mosquitos were insane. Like a fool I didn't take the reports seriously enough before I went (mosquitos usually leave me alone and I don't react to mosquito bites, so I thought I would be OK), so all I had for protection was a long-sleeved shirt, thin enough for a determined mosquito to get through, and a five-year old bottle of Herbal Armor bug spray.

On the first day I noticed that very few mosquitos were landing on my left shoulder and arm, while I nearly always had a group of mosquitos landing on my right shoulder and arm. So I paid close attention over the following five days.

It wasn't even close. I never had more than one or two mosquitos at a time on my left (and usually none at all), while I nearly always had five or more on my right. The time of day didn't seem to matter. Or the position of the sun or the direction of the wind, if there was any. While the SHT generally travels south and west, the results were the same no matter the direction of travel. There was only one time I noticed five mosquitos on my left, and I couldn't determine anything unusual about me or my surroundings at the time.

I can't compare my legs because my pants, socks, and shoes were too thick for mosquitos.

The old, herbal bug spray I had didn't do much to help so I didn't use it very much. It's possible I did a better job putting it on my left side, but I was thinking about this as I applied it so I don't think so.

So I'm wondering if it is possible that the blood on my right is fresher or sweeter or something? Or is there another reason mosquitos might prefer one side to the other?

Comment: Perhaps you sweat more on that side, and the aroma is more attractive. I sweat more on my right side than my left, even when the only activity is walking.

Comment: I assume that Herbal Armor is an insect repellent (never heard before). Are you applying it with the right hand? Couldn't it be that you simply missed the right shoulder?

Comment: @Weather Vane: I've never noticed that I sweat more on one side, but that seems like a solid hypothesis. I'll try to test it the next time I go for a long walk in the heat.

Comment: @FluidCode: I don't think it's a matter of how I applied the bug spray. As I said, I was thinking about this problem as I applied it so I was careful to apply it evenly.

Comment: If you're right-handed, your right arm might be more muscular and so mosquito vision sees veins as more pronounced on the right arm.

Comment: Could even be a blood circulation thing. If you don’t get answers here, maybe on a biology stackexchange.